# Infer a generic type on a Java class

Tags: java, generics

Imagine a class declared like this:

```java
public abstract class AbstractController<D, W extends AbstractWrapper<D>> {
  protected final W wrapper;

  // ...

  protected void onChange(D prev, D curr) {}
}
```

The idea here is to be able to define specialized ones based on a data type and a wrapper class that might contain utilities specific to the use case:

```java
public class BooleanController extends AbstractController<Boolean, SimpleToggle> {
  // ...

  @Override
  protected void onChange(Boolean prev, Boolean curr) {
    // Do something with the inherited this.wrapper, which has a type of SimpleToggle
  }
}

public class SimpleToggle extends AbstractWrapper<Boolean> {
  // ...
}
```

My question is in a situation like this, where the first generic type parameter for AbstractController will always match the generic type parameter for AbstractWrapper (in this example, Boolean), is there any way to infer the type of D for AbstractController in a way that would simplify the typing, so that BooleanController would just extend AbstractController<SimpleToggle>?

Obviously it's not that much more to type, but it always bugged me that I couldn't find a way to automatically infer/detect the type of D here.

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that in Java...